# PHP regex match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to find matching ID 123 in my url. I tried the following:

```
$stringurl = "/category/any-text-string/123";

preg_match( '/\/category\/[\w|\W]+\/(\d+)/', $stringurl, $matches);
```

the result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(21) "/category/any-text-string/123" [1]=> string(2) "123" }
```

stringurl can be "/category/any-text-string/123?querystring"

I need advice whether above expression is ok or there is any better regex pattern than above, as I'm quite new in regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following RegExp will better suit your needs:

```
/^\/category\/[^\/]+\/(\d+)(?:\?.*)?$/
```

- Use `^` and `$` to match beginning and end of string. Without them, you'll match strings like: `"/abc/category/any-text/123"` and `"/category/any-text/123abc"`
- check explicitly for the `"?querystring"` portion. make it optional.
- use `\/[^/]+\/` to match any text string (except slashes) between two slashes. If you don't exclude slashes, then you'll also match strings like: `"/category/abc/def?a=/123"`

General notes:

- Within a character class just list the chars you want to match, don't separate them with `|` (unless `|` is one of the chars you want to match).  So in your original regexp, `[\w|\W]` should have just been `[\w\W]`.
- Don't use `[\w\W]` to mean "any character".  Just use `.`.

Comment: ty Lee. it works perfectly and the notes is awesome especially for beginner like me. really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

why so hard? try

```
$stringurl = "/category/any-text-string/123";
$url = explode('/',$stringurl);
in_array('123',$url); // Returns TRUE if found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
```

Comment: Yes, this is the good solution for the question. And if you need to find '123' at last of the $stringurl then check the last element of the array $url

Comment: thanks diEcho, i need to match url with /category/text/id, sorry i forgot to mention this